# Java import confusion

Tags: java, import

What is the difference between:

```
java.awt.*;
```

and:

```
java.awt.event.*;
```

I find both in many programs.

Answer (score 33):

Packages in Java are not nested.

When you `import java.awt.*`, you are only importing all the classes and interfaces that are in the package `java.awt` - you are **not** importing all the packages that are under `java.awt`, such as `java.awt.event`.

Even though it looks like packages are nested (i.e., it looks like as if `java.awt.event` is a "subpackage" of `java.awt`), this is not really the case. You should regard `java.awt` and `java.awt.event` as two different, unrelated packages that happen to have a common part in their names.

Comment: isnt it true that import java.awt.* automatically imports java.awt.event also?

Comment: No - that was Jesper's point.  
import java.awt.*; imports every class whose package is exactly java.awt.  It does not import any class whose package merely starts with java.awt.

Answer (score 6):

The first only imports types from the java.awt package (but not its subpackages), and the other imports only from java.awt.event (but not from any other packages).

While packages in Java can (and should be) organized in a hierarchy, the import statement tends to be "conservative" - when you import all the types from within that package, you get only those specifically at that level, not at lower level in the hierarchy.

I think that the rationale behind it is to avoid spurious imports. It is generally a good idea to import as little as you can - just the bare necessities, to avoid coupling, dependencies, and ambiguities (e.g., what happens if a new class is added to the package with a name that conflicts with a name in another package?). That's why if you use Eclipse to organize your imports, it will actually add specific import statements inside of the asterisk version, even though that means extra lines. Importing everything in subpackages would be even worse, you'll really get everything.

In addition, a common practice is to put special purpose classes and implementation-specific classes,in their own subpackages. Often, you specifically want to avoid importing them unless crucial. Again, importing the entire subtree would conflict with that.

Answer (score 1):

Like many have said before.

import java.awt.*   won't import any classes in java.awt.event...

And the difference between those two package is  that java.awt.*  include classes like a Frame, Button, etc   and the java.awt.event.* package include all event / listener that can happen.

Example, to create a Button  you need the class java.awt.Button  but if you want that any action happen when you click the Button, you need a  java.awt.event.ActionListener  that will "wait" for the click,  then produce a java.awt.event.ActionEvent.

Answer (score 0):

`java.awt.*` is *not* a regular expression, which is what I think you are expecting/thinking.

`java.awt.*` will give you only the classes in that exact package, and not the nested packages.  Imagine the name space collisions involved with below!

```
import com.*
```

It should be noted that it is considered bad practice to use `*`. Explicate class name imports are preferred.

For further reading: [Wikipedia: Namespace (Computer Science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace_%28computer_science%29)

Comment: Is even import * supported? :-o

Comment: @Oscar Reyes: No, "import *" does not exist in Java.

Comment: agreed, does not work (which actually surprises me).  i'll change it so as not to confuse anyone...