# Why does [import java.awt.*] not also include [import java.awt.event.ActionEvent]?

Tags: java, import

Evening,

I was playing around with a little swing application, and I added a button which was to respond to being pressed. Therefore I needed to implement ActionListener. I had already added this line:

```
import java.awt.*;
```

but it informed me that it could not find the "ActionListener" class.
So after a few moments I ended up
with this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
```

I was under the assumption that the awt.* part meant that it was importing all sub-packages under the awt umbrella. Apparently this isn't the case. Can someone please clarify this problem for me?

Comment: What use is the first dot `.` in `import.java.wat.*;`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java import confusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335327/java-import-confusion)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import java.awt.*;
```

This imports all **classes** under in the awt package, not subpackages.

The main reason is that java packages are not nested, even if their names makes you think they are. `java.awt` and `java.awt.event` can be seen as two unrelated packages.