# Why some Java codes imports same package again?

Tags: java, import, playframework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java import confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335327/java-import-confusion)

When i read play frameworks documentation, I found this.

```
import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;
```

In the first line itself they have imported all the classes under play package. Then what is the use of second line. Check this [link](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaGlobal). Go to 'Providing an application error page' section.

Correct me if i'm wrong in imports concept.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Shame on me for not concentrating on basic things. Eclipse is responsible for that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Correct me if i'm wrong in imports concept.

You are.

Something like this:

```
import foo.bar.*;
```

*only* imports types from the `foo.bar` package. It *doesn't* import from "subpackages" such as `foo.bar.baz`.

It's very easy to test this:

```
import java.util.*;

class Test {
    public void foo() {
        Pattern p = null;
    }
}
```

That won't compile, but if you add:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
```

then it will.

Java doesn't really think of packages as forming a hierarchy. *We* do, as humans, but as far as the Java language is concerned, the packages `java.util` and `java.util.regex` are entirely unrelated.

Answer (score 2):

```
import play.*;
```

will import all the types within; except those which are inside a sub-package.

```
import play.mvc.*;
```

will import all the types within `mvc` package, which is sub-pckage within `play`.

You'll find this answer also helpful: [Java import confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335327/java-import-confusion)

Answer (score 1):

The first line will import all classes, enums and interfaces in the same level of play.* but no subpackages. Therefore you need the second line.

Answer (score 0):

They are different packages. There is no concept of sub-packages in Java. The classes imported by play.* might as well be under work.*. From the standpoint of the JVM they have nothing to do with the classes under play.mvc.*. The naming convention is just a convenience for you to know that the packages are related, and play.mvc probably depends heavily on play.