# Importing classes from External JAR files in JSP

Tags: jsp, lucene

To search in the Lucene index I caught the query of an user by a Web User Interface in JSP. In JSP, I have written  short JAVA code to parse the query and  call the Lucene index searcher to search for the query. But the problem is that it is repeatedly giving compilation error as "Query cannot be resolved, MultiFieldQueryParser cannot be resolved ...". So none of the Lucene classes are getting resolved. The code is as follows:

File name : result.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" import="java.util.*,java.io.*,org.apache.lucene.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%! String query; %>
<%
    query=request.getParameter("myQuery");
%>
<form name="frm" method="post" action="result.jsp">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td width="22%">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="78%">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp; </td>
<td><input type="text" name="myQuery" placeholder="Type here"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
  Directory dir=new FSDirectory.open(new File(path of index directory));
  QueryParser parser=new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, new String[] 
  {"title","address","city"},new BooleanClause.Occur[]{BooleanClause.Occur.MUST,
  BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD, BooleanCaluse.Occur.SHOULD},new StandardAnalyzer());
  Query query=parser.parse(query);
  IndexSearcher searcher=new Indexsearcher(dir,true);
  TopDocs hits=searcher.search(query,20);
  searcher.close();
  dir.close();
%>
<p>Query phrase is : <%=query%></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I cannot understand why any of the classes of Lucene are not getting resolved even after importing Lucene above. So I am asking whether anyone can please help me to fix the above code. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java import confusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335327/java-import-confusion)

Answer (score 2):

**Rule of thumb:** importing abc.xyz.* will ONLY import all the classes in the package abc.xyz, but NOT  the classes in the package abc.xyz.ijk.

Ex: "org.apache.lucene.*" will NOT import "org.apache.lucene.store.Directory"

To resolve the above error, import following packages / classes.

1) "org.apache.lucene.store.Directory" or "org.apache.lucene.store.*"

2) "org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParser"

3) "org.apache.lucene.queryParser.MultiFieldQueryParser"

4) "org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanClause"

5) "org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer"

6) org.apache.lucene.search.TopDocs

7) org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher

I might have missed a class or two. Just follow the "rule of thumb" and import the missing classes with full length package names.

BTW, **[NEVER use scriptlets in a JSP](https://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/WhyNotUseScriptlets)**, i.e. direct Java code in JSP. It is a bad approach.

You can find other resources to understand it better.

Comment: I understood that one should not use scriptlet inside JSP. Many suggested of using JSTL instead of using scriptlets. But in the above case I have no clue how will I use JSTL to avoid scriptlet. So I am asking if anyone can please give an idea to handle it. Thank you.

Comment: @Joy, that'd be a different question. Post another question with your query, you will surely get better and comprehensive answers over there than here in the comments..

Comment: welcome, let me know whether the above answer solved your initial problem specified in the question.